# Add spot color (direct tone) to a PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

Does any one have example code to add a direct tone to a PDF?
It is to a printer production to detect a rectangle to cut up.
this spot color is named « decoupe » and i need it for the rectangle.
I don’t need to modify the CMYK value of the separation.

I need to had a color named "decoupe" to the document and use this color to create a rectangle with this color, the printer detects this color to cut the document to the format. In the PDF document the line should be like that: 14 0 obj [/Separation /decoupe /DeviceCMYK << /Range [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1] /C0 [0 0 0 0] /C1 [0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000] /FunctionType 2 /Domain [0 1] /N 1>>] endobj

Comment: I don't know if I have understood the question. What you may want is a color from the PDSeparation class. With that, maybe you can improve your question? Also explain what you mean with "trace" and "direct tone". Do you want to add colors (e.g. colored lines) to an existing PDF?

Comment: I need to had a color named "decoupe" to the document and use this color to create a rectangle with this color,  the printer detect this color to cut the document to the format. In the Pdf doc the line should be like that 
14 0 obj
[/Separation /decoupe /DeviceCMYK << /Range [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1] /C0 [0 0 0 0] /C1 [0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000]  /FunctionType 2 /Domain [0 1] /N 1>>]
endobj
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This code adds a rectangle to an existing PDF with a spot color. I changed the c1 values to 1 1 1 1 so that something gets visible (yours was 0 0 0 0).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(....);

    COSArray array = new COSArray();
    array.add(COSName.SEPARATION);
    array.add(COSName.getPDFName("decoupe"));
    array.add(COSName.DEVICECMYK); // alternate color

    COSDictionary fdict = new COSDictionary();
    fdict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 2);
    COSArray range = new COSArray();
    range.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(1));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(1));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(1));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    range.add(COSInteger.get(1));
    COSArray domain = new COSArray();
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(1));
    COSArray c0 = new COSArray();
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0"));
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0"));
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0"));
    c0.add(COSFloat.get("0"));
    COSArray c1 = new COSArray();
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("1"));
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("1"));
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("1"));
    c1.add(COSFloat.get("1"));
    fdict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, domain);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.RANGE, range);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C0, c0);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C1, c1);
    fdict.setInt(COSName.N, 1);
    PDFunctionType2 func = new PDFunctionType2(fdict);
    array.add(func); // tint transform

    PDColorSpace spotColorSpace = new PDSeparation(array);

    PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
    PDColor color = new PDColor(new float[]{0.5f}, spotColorSpace);
    cs.setStrokingColor(color);
    cs.setLineWidth(10);
    cs.addRect(50, 50, 300, 300);
    cs.stroke();
    cs.close();
    doc.save(...);
}
```

What I used as help: the source code of PDSeparation.java, and the CreateGradientShadingPDF.java example from the source code download, that one has a type 2 function that I could easily copy and modify.

Comment: exactly what i needed, many thanks Tilman, now i better understand the PDSeparation for PDF doc.